# how to create function with dynamic name in php

Tags: php

I want to create class which will dynamically generate getXXX and setXXX function of all the variable in which this class get extended.

can we use "user call func array" or "user call func"

any example or idea how to do this?

```
class B extends A
{
 var $name;
 var $email;
 var ....
}
```

I want some type of coding in class A which will generate get and set method for all the variable in class B in which it is extended.

And also I want to create other methods other than get and set which will use variable name of the extended class

something like this getbyname() or similar function which will use variable of extended class

Comment: Why you not use magic methods? `__get(), __set()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: I also want to create other function other than get and set, which will use variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Getters and setters are a solved problem. You can use the magic **[`__get()` and `__set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)** methods.

Know this, there's nothing better than actually implementing all the getters and setters manually! If you have too many, your class probably has too many functions and needs to be split down!